# How do I retrieve custom marker coordinates in HERE Maps API for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, here-api

How do I retrieve custom marker coordinates in HERE Maps API for Javascript?

This is how I add a custom marker:

```
var marker = new nokia.maps.map.StandardMarker([52.51, 13.4], {
   text: "Hi!", // Small label
   draggable: true // Make the marker draggable
});

map.objects.add(marker);
```

The problem: I need to get new coordinates when a user drags this marker to another position and clicks 'ok' (so no listeners are needed).

Neither `var 123 = marker(coordinate); alert(123);`nor `var 123 = marker.coordinate; alert(123);` do the trick. The API seems to be silent about that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be pretty simple:

```
var latitude = marker.coordinate.latitude.toString();
```

Comment: Hey Jan, this does not work anymore. Do you know, what the solution is now?

Comment: Here's the documentation for markers in the new API version - https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics/markers.html. I'm no longer into HERE Maps, but I would suggest dumping the marker object to console, expanding its properties and seeing how you can access its coordinates

Answer (score 2):

As of 2021 the actual way to go is:

```
marker.getGeometry().lat;
marker.getGeometry().lng;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should do:

```
marker.getPosition()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will return it:

```
marker.getPosition().lat;
```

and

```
marker.getPosition().lng;
```